# How to get the ID of a Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the ID of an element that I found by using `getElementsByClassName()`
Here is what my code looks like:

```
let className = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class')
for (let i = 0; i < className.length; i++) {
    if (className.GETID.toLowerCase().includes('some text')) {
        //  do something
    }
}
```

So basically what I want is to replace GETID with some kind of method or anyway to get the id of the Element that I have found by using the `getElementsByClassName()` method.

Comment: `someElement.id` will give you the ID. So, in your case, `className[i].id`

Comment: You can get any attribute for an element using [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute). In your case: `element.getAttribute('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id). Note that this is not a method as your question asks for, but a property instead. This is how you'd use it with your code:

```
let className = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class')
for (let i = 0; i < className.length; i++) {
    if (className[i].id.toLowerCase().includes('some text')) {
        //  do something
    }
}
```

The `.id` property is set for every DOM element regardless of whether it was retrieved with `getElementById()`.

Comment: @blex Good call. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I will accept this answer in 6 minutes, StackOverflow says I cannot accept it for another 6 minutes. This fixed my problem, thank you!